# Android Actionbar, get specific tab screen position

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I have an `Activity`, in which I used actionbar tabs, the Activity has multiple tabs. 
I want to display a walkthrough when the application starts. 
In the walkthrough I have to display  a message below each tab, for this I have to get the position left/top of each tab. 
How get the position of each tab in `ActionBar`?

I have a one more problem, `onConfigurationChanged` tabs becomes navigationlist(spinner) in this case I have to determine if it if tabs/spinner and display the walkthrough accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**NEVER use NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST and onNavigationItemSelected it is not worth it !**

```
     @Override
     public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId)

    You also cannot use menu's to do this:

   @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
  {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

due to inflation ordering.
Reasons:

(1) it generates a "hidden" spinner, for which you can not get the id.
(2) you cannot customize this spinner
(3) you save 30 lines of code, but are permanently limited if you want to add a second bi-directional spinner 
(4) not even in the special case of "simple code" (one spinner), you lose to much.
(5) you cannot use tabs.

the key is actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_custom);
and spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()...
for each spinner.
Trust me I lost hours trying each solution.
```